# Smarty compile_dir permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, smarty

After moving php-files from windows to linux(centos) I started getting the following permissions errors:

```
ERRNO: 2
TEXT: rename(/tmp/wrtwetuti,/var/www/site1/presentation//compile_dir/ee63ba1108c61f830b5d6155f21b1bcd04684f7e.file.category.tpl.php): Permission denied
LOCATION: /var/www/site1/libs/smarty_3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php, line 48, at September 9, 2011, 4:05 am
```

When for testing purposes chmoded compile_dir to 777, the problem goes away.

I wonder if anybody knows a solutions for it.
Would installing suPHP solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`compile_dir`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.compile.dir.tpl) is *supposed* to be writable by the web server (and also outside your web root). So you should:

- move it out of your web root
- assign ownership to the web server user
- chmod it to 700

The fact that on your Windows install the default `compile_dir` was also writable by the web server is typical for that OS, and doesn't mean that there is something to fix on Linux.

Comment: why would I need to move it out of web root?

Comment: @Eugene: On principle, because the documentation recommends it. As a practical matter, because if you do not then unless your web server is specifically configured to forbid it anyone on the internet might be able to get hold of your compiled Smarty templates. This would allow them to learn things about your code that you might not want them to know.

Comment: Thank you! So moving compile_dir from /var/www/site1/presentation/compile_dir/ to say /var/compile_dir/ would do?

Comment: @Jon, could you kindly explain how to find out the "web server user" name? Or how to "assign ownership to the web server user"

Comment: @klm123: Assuming Linux, for the web server user name: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7771586/50079. To change ownership: `sudo chown new_owner compile_dir`. Standard stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this page: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl
"Smarty will need write access (windows users please ignore) to the $compile_dir and $cache_dir directories (templates_c/ and cache/), so be sure the web server user account can write to them".

hope this helps.