# How do I find out, which user is running the current php script?

Tags: php, apache

How do we determine which user the php script is running under when I run the script on server? Is it running under the same user as apache or phpmyadmin by chance? My question maybe wrongly framed but I want to know which user so that I set appropriate permission for different folders in /var

Comment: Googling `php determine user` will give you the needed information

Comment: +1 yfgi.... (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php#57624)

Comment: You will need to provide some more information to allow us to help you here, i'm afraid.

Comment: why all the downvotes? this is a pretty decent question.

Comment: @rambocoder Because it is _so_ decent it is _so_ easy to google which means _someone_ is very lazy... :)

Comment: Related: [How to check what user php is running as?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7771586/2157640)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Execute `whoami`:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

Comment: Hmm second person downvote after it was edited. As it stands this does work see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as

Comment: Hehe, edited it just to be able to remove my downvote (it is locked after a certain time..)

Comment: Thanks :). I wasn't really complaining about yours. You were right lol.

Comment: While this works it isn't a particularly effective solution, and the solution below it using posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()) is both more efficient and able to work on servers with shell exec locked down.

Comment: I prefer the `id` command myself, you'll get an output like this:

`uid=1004(testsite) gid=1005(testsite) groups=1005(testsite),1004(sftp)`

Answer (score 9):

If you have [posix functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php) available (enabled by default in most Linux-based environments) then you can use [`posix_geteuid`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-geteuid.php) and [`posix_getpwuid`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-geteuid.php) to get the name of the user (at least in non-Windows environments) like so:

```
$pwu_data = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
$username = $pwu_data['name'];
```

Another (more expensive) way to do it would be to use a shell-executing function like exec to run whoami:

```
$username = exec('whoami');
```

or even the backticks (although you may need to trim the linebreak off):

```
$username = `whoami`;
```

I personally have only ever needed to get the username of the user running the script for PHP scripts that run in the shell (on the command-line). Typically, scripts that run in the process of building the response to a request that the web server is handling will be run as the web server user, such as www-data, apache, etc. In Apache, the user that runs the apache/httpd processes is set with the [User](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#user) directive.

Important note: [`get_current_user`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) does NOT give you the username of the user running the script, but instead gives you the OWNER of the script. Some of the answers here (appropriately down-voted) are suggesting to use `get_current_user`, but that will not give you the username of the user running the current script.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use "whoami". When you execute a process the user will not necessarily be the same as the effective user during running of a script. But in any case "id" would provide much more useful information. Instead call get_current_user(). So simple!

Answer (score -3):

Use this:

```
echo get_current_user();
```

Make sure to read the comments because it looks like this answer doesn't actually do what you want.

Comment: This is actually the "owner of the current PHP script" as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Answer (score -4):

Use this:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
```

this variable may or may not be set.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. He wants to know the *system* user