# Symfony2: How to move file from tmp directory to definitve position

Tags: php, symfony

I'm on a Mac and I'm trying to create an image in the PHP tmp directory, and then move it to its definitive location.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public function download()
{
    // Get the remote file extension
    $remoteImageExtension = explode('.', $this->getRemoteUri()->getPath());
    $remoteImageExtension = array_pop($remoteImageExtension);
    $fs = new Filesystem();

    $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image.') . '.' . $remoteImageExtension;

    /** @todo: Refact: Pass this as constructor parameter so it will be possible to unit test it */
    $client = new Client();

    // Get and save file
    $client->get($this->getRemoteUri(), ['save_to' => $tempImage]);

    $tempImage = new File($tempImage);

    try {
        if ($fs->exists($tempImage))
        {
            die('Temporary file exists');
            $fs->copy($tempImage, $this->getDownloadRootDir() . $this->getName() . '.' . $remoteImageExtension);
        } else {
            die('Temporary file doesn\'t exist');
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    // die(print_r($tempImage));
    // Move the file to its definitive location
    //die($this->getDownloadRootDir() . ' | ' . $this->getName());
    /*try {
        $tempImage->move(
            $this->getDownloadRootDir(),
            $this->getName() . '.' . $remoteImageExtension
        );
    } catch (FileException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }*/

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getName();
}
```

As you can see I've put some `die()` in the code to print some information during the execution.

Doing this, I know the temporary file is correctly created, but it isn't moved to its new location.

I've read around that it could be a problem of permissions on destination folder, but, changing them with returns me an error about an illegal user (I'm on a Mac!):

```
$ chown -R www-data /Users/Aerendir/Documents/JooServer/_Projects/path/to/symfony_project/web/images/path/to/destination_folder
chown: www-data: illegal user name
```

I have tried both the `Filesystem::copy()` and the `File::move()` methods (as you can see from the source code provided), but the file isn't moved.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

UPDATE
Trying to know [which is my current Apache user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088424/1399706) I see it is correctly set to my main system user (Aerendir).