# Why are php and apache granted different privileges?

Tags: php, apache

I have 770 permission set on all of my server files and the apache user (www-data) has been added to the group owner for each of the files. Apache works just fine but I have to have at least 774 permissions for the php scripts to work. Does php run under a different user?

Comment: It depends on your system config. Find out: [How to check what user php is running as?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7771586)

Comment: From my research I gathered that php scripts were run from apache directly which is why I was confused.

Comment: How did you arrive at 770 as a good permission level to use?

Comment: Is it relevant? This is just a private server for testing and developing and I have a few sites on it. I am using ftp to allow different users to access their own directories so I used groups to facilitate the whole thing and as far as I'm concerned if I haven't added a user to a group then they have no business seeing my or other people's files. Hence the 0 for others.

Comment: It's very relevant, especially since you've jeopardized your security in an effort to establish security. Are users prevented from creating php files and accessing them in an apache server?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I checked the user and it is running as www-data which has full permissions as it is in the group that "owns" the files. I still have to grant at least read privileges to "others" for the scripts to execute.

Comment: If I'm a user and I make a script named lol.php, are you saying there's no ability for it to ever be loaded via apache unless you specifically go out of your way to enable that permission set?

Comment: Exactly. These aren't web developers. I have content management systems in place so they can add photos/ect, not run scripts.

Comment: Oh okay, I think that was the misunderstanding that most of us would assume happens all the time here. At least you know what you're doing. I simply haven't answered your question because from a permissions standpoint apache should be able to read and execute code as long as the file is readable. You technically wouldn't even need rwx on that user or group.

Comment: In fact not only should it work... I've already replicated what you were trying to do on a box with 0040 as the permissions, root as the owner, and apache as the group with no issues :/

Comment: I just don't get it. I've had this problem before as well and I could make it work by changing the permissions but it has just been bugging me not knowing.

Comment: You're positive apache is running as www-data? In older versions it would run as apache. If you changed this, did you restart apache? There's just no reason a file should have to be world readable if the group is correct.

Comment: I'm positive. I think I must just be experiencing a bug.