# PHP script fails when called from a browser but not from CLI

Tags: php

This is driving me nuts.

I've reduced my problem to this: I have a simple file 'test.php' that invokes a php file (this is from a bigger application, so in fact we need to execute many php scripts from a main script):

```
<?php

 exec("php /var/www/setActive.php 273 1 2>&1",$arO,$nO);
echo $nO.'|'.implode(',',$arO);
```

The original path for setActive.php is way longer, I shortened it for this example.

Now, if I try:

```
[root@stg]# sudo -u apache php test.php
```

I get:

```
0|
```

Great, this means the setActive.php script ran smoothly.

Now, if I try it from a browser or from curl:

```
[root@stg]#curl http://my.url/path/test.php
```

This is what I get:

```
1|Could not open input file: /var/www/setActive.php
```

I already reviewed all the permissions. Apache user has access to all directories and files.
This was working ok in another server. I reviewed the php.ini files and there is no difference between them.

Maybe is a option that I'm not seeing, or an apache config option. I'm ran out of ideas.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

I have Linux, Cent OS. PHP 5.3.23

Comment: what do you get in the apache logs?

Comment: Is `my.url` the same server?

Comment: are you sure that the script is accessible (file permissions, right Path, accessible by VirtualHost)?

Comment: Does the script run as the `apache` user via the web server? You can find the user running the script, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as

Comment: Have you tried using include instead of exec?

Comment: @xdazz Yes, is the same server.

Comment: @Phil: Yes, it runs with 'apache' as user.

Comment: @Charles Forest: Those files comes from different applications. So we need to run them as any other external file.

Comment: @user3462228 Did you check from the PHP script using the answers in that linked post? PHP may be executing as a different user via SuExec or similar

Comment: @Phil: Yes, I wanted to be sure, and try with exec('whoami') a few hours ago. The user is 'apache'.

Comment: @user3462228 Could be `open_basedir` or some other sandboxing security measure. Sorry, just clutching at straws now :(

Comment: From the command line you have to use `sudo`, yeah? So why should your application get to do it without? This might be a step toward your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Comment: @Phil open_basedir is not set. Is there another one like this?

Comment: @Shaun Scovil: In the example I'm using sudo to run the script as the apache user (sudo -u). If I omit the sudo, it runs as 'root', and the result is the same (successful execution).

Comment: @user3462228 what if instead of `exec` you put `var_dump(file_exists('/var/www/setActive.php'))` and `var_dump(file_get_contents('/var/www/setActive.php'))`; ? is php able to find and read the file?

Comment: @user3462228 [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/)

Comment: The difference appears to be that users www-user (or whatever default for web is) and apache must have different permissions to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If permissions etc.. are all ok, possibly the apache config. in your setup has the 'ChrootDir' set:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#chrootdir

This uses the syscall chroot() and the view for '/' dir for that process starts from this setup dir, and hence everything should be relative to it.