# "Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in" while running as owner of parent

Tags: php, linux, apache, chmod, bitnami

I'm running this script:

```
$dir = 'images';
if (!file_exists($dir) ) {
    mkdir ($dir, 0644);
}
```

It returns this error:

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in
>   /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/file.php on line xx.

Apperently i do not have the rights to create the folder. I found the following:

- htdocs has chmod set to 755
- The owner of htdocs is daemon (lrwxrwxrwx 1 daemon  daemon  27 Aug  1 12:16 htdocs -> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs)
- I created a file with php while temp. using chmod 777 and then used this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771686/1139465 to figure out the owner, that was daemon (Array ( [name] => daemon [passwd] => x [uid] => 1 [gid] => 1 [gecos] => daemon [dir] => /usr/sbin [shell] => /bin/sh ) done)

I have an intallation of the Bitnami LAMP solution.

Comment: Check the owner of /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs, not the symlink.

Comment: Hi specify  whole path not just final directory and check permission $dir = 'images';

Comment: @devon that was the problem. I changed ownership of the symlink. I did ls -l /opt/bitnami/apache2/ to find out that the owner was actually different then expected. The command sudo chown -R username:username /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs change it. Now the code does work.

Comment: @volkinc sorry, was not that clear, i tried both (full and short path), but indeed the full url in combinatino with Devon's solution did work.