# PHP: Not creating CRON file one way, but it another (cannot tell the reason for the difference)

Tags: php, bash, shell, permissions, cron

Sorry for the vague title, but I don't know how better to describe this problem...

I have one PHP function whose job it is to create a customer, named, simply `customer.php`.  Part of the script looks like this:

```
//...code above...
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/cron.php"));
//....more code below...
```

The `cron.php` that it refers to is literally just three lines of code, and two of them are logging calls (those functions reside in an imported script in `customer.php`, and they ARE working, as shown below):

```
<?php
saveLog("cron.php PRE custname= $custname by ".get_current_user());
$tmp = exec("sudo ./addcron.sh $custname", $output);
saveLog("cron.php POST tmp=$tmp output=".formatArray($output));
```

The `addcron.sh` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "* * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/cron.php" > $1
chown root:root $1
mv $1 /etc/cron.d/
```

When I execute the `customer.php` file I see the log records, like so:

```
cron.php PRE custname= test123 by root
cron.php POST tmp= output=Array()
```

So I know that the `$custname` variable -- literally the only thing I pass -- is getting populated correctly.

I created a `test.php` file which is a stripped-down version of the `customer.php` file.  It looks entirely like this:

```
<?php
require_once("../../local_functions.php");
$custname = "xyz".date('YmdHis');
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/cron.php"));
```

Note that all four of these files, `cron.php`, `customer.php`, `test.php` and even `addcron.sh` all reside in the same directory.  They are all owned by `root`.

The odd thing is: when I visit `test.php` in my browser, the CRON script is created.  When it is run by `customer.php` it is not.  The log looks identical.

I suspected that the reason for this is that the `customer.php` file is called by forwarding from a loading page, but when I set up the same type of forwarding for `test.php`, it worked.

The loading page code is simply like so:

```
<div id="processing">
    <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse''></i>
    Hang tight...
</div>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        document.location.href = "./customer.php";
   });
</script>
```

The loading page is also owned by root.  The permissions on the files look like so:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2630 Oct 18 00:26 loading.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 8995 Nov  4 00:16 customer.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1352 Nov 17 04:34 cron.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  286 Nov 17 04:50 test.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  129 Oct 18 00:26 addcron.sh
```

Searching the server logs for `test123` and `xyz2016` both turn up nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: What supply the password to sudo?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: There is this line in your customer.php script: `$tmp = exec("sudo ./addcron.sh $custname", $output);`. How is sudo set up to get the password, or, is sudo set up to bypass the use of a password for the user that runs the script. It is usually a really bad idea running php as root.

Comment: Please [read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7771586/6843677).

Comment: I'm already doing the user check.  In one of my files I'm logging with the line: `saveLog("cron.php PRE custname= $custname by ".get_current_user());`  That outputs as `cron.php PRE custname= test123 by root`