# Cannot do Git Commit on Windows / PHP

Tags: php, windows, git, git-commit

I'm using `Windows` / `PHP`.

By using a `PHP` script I wanna make a `commit` but this operation fails.

For this I'm using the following code:

```
<?
$command = "git commit -am .";
shell_exec($command);
?>
```

I also tried using `chdir` to be sure I'm in the Git repository directory but it doesn't work (anyway I think I don't need `chdir`. The problem is another thing).

Normally from the `Windows console` I use the same command above (which works perfectly):

```
> git commit -am .
```

Also, if from the Windows console I do:

```
> php myscript.php
```

it works properly. But if through the browser I go to the url:

```
http://localhost/mysite/myscript.php
```

Then, the commit doesn't go thru. But as I said you before, the status is read properly from the browser.

In the other hand, if I just check the `status` by doing:

```
<?
$command = "git status";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output
?>
```

Then the `Git status` is returned correctly.

Any idea on how to make the `commit` works through `PHP` on `Windows`?

**[EDIT 1]**

I checked the Apache error log and I saw that everytime I tried to do a commit there was an error saying that I need to specify email and name. Then I did that (via PHP too). But now I'm getting another error, which says: fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense. (on the Apache error log) when I try to make the following commit via PHP: shell_exec("git commit -am 'my commit message here'");. Do you know what to do now?

Comment: Does `git commit -am .` work from the Windows terminal? I *suspect* the `.` and the `-a` are redundant.

Comment: Yes, it works. I use this command regularly and I wanna integrate it into a PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the files with `git add .` and provide a message as a string argument to `-m`:

**Commit with: `-am`**

```
$command = 'git commit -am "php wuz here"';
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);
shell_exec($escaped_command);
```

**edit 1**

the `git commit -am .` is working for me, too, perhaps you just need the `escapeshellcmd` and single quotes. i had trouble with outer double quotes when i tested it.

**edit 2**

Windows 7

[image]

**edit 3**

> Solution (validated by the author of the thread. It works!):

```
$command = 'git config user.name "Will Smith"';
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);
$result = shell_exec($escaped_command);

$command = 'git config user.email "myemail@gmail.com"';
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);
$result = shell_exec($escaped_command);

$command = 'git commit -am "my commit message here"';
$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);
$result = shell_exec($escaped_command);
```

**Important:** Pay attention to:

1. the quotes and double quotes (need to be in that order)
2. `escapeshellcmd`
3. the `Apache log` is very important to know what is happening behind the scene (and debug)

Comment: your code didn't work for me. are you using windows or linux?

Comment: windows and linux both showing the same result.  when you say, "it doesn't work", does that mean you get an error or no output or it just doesn't create a commit?

Comment: I added other experiments to my post above based on what you did. `Summarizing:` if from the Windows console I do: `> php myscript.php` the `commit` goes thru, but if I access to `myscript.php` through the browser, then the `commit` fails. In both cases, Windows console and browser, the `status` check works properly.

Comment: if it fails when accessing it via the web browser, it is a permissions problem and not a git syntax or `shell_exec` problem

Comment: if you can `sudo su` to become another user, find out what user your webserver is (`shell_exec(\`who\`);`) and `sudo su` to that user to find out what the *git* is going on when you run that command directly as that user. (ah, you may not have `who` on windows...well, that is an issue isn't it.  what webserver are you using?)

Comment: ah, the `git` binary may not be in the path of the webserver user. check that.

Comment: I'm totally agree with that. Do you know how to configure the permissions for Apache on Windows in order it can do a Git commit?

Comment: check [this thread on determining the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as) php is running under.  i think you need a new question - we have determined the solution to this one.

Comment: I'm using Windows, not Linux, so Linux solutions don't apply for me. I think Git is on the path of the webserver user since the `git status` works properly (double checked on Windows system). The problem is with the `commit`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129654/discussion-between-david-smith-and-webjuju).

Comment: [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as) has solutions that are platform independent.

Comment: I checked the Apache error log and I saw that everytime I tried to do a commit there was an error saying that I need to specify email and name. Then I did that (via PHP too). But now I'm  getting another error, which says: `fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.` (on the Apache error log) when I try to make the following commit via PHP: `shell_exec("git commit -am 'my commit message here'");`. Do you know what to do now?

Comment: i think you can drop the -a.  but you will have to run the `git add .` first and that won't add deleted files. see my screenshot how i added using `git add .` and then separately called the `git commit -m "message here"`.

Comment: are you escaping the shell arguments?  if not, that's your issue with the `-a`

Comment: escaping the shell arguments is very important

Comment: indeed! indeed!