# get_current_user() Says Current User Is 'root', and 'root' Owns the Log File, Yet file_put_contents For the Log File Returns False

Tags: php

I'm wanting to log certain events to a file. Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
$logFile = '/var/logs/private/do_not_backup/lms2.0_test_errors.log';
$logMessage = 'New Common Quiz Review about to be created with userQuizId of ' . $userQuizId . '\n\n';

$filePutResult = file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage, FILE_APPEND);

if (!$filePutResult){
  $currentUser = get_current_user();
  die ($currentUser . ' could not append ' . $logMessage . ' to log file ' . $logFile . '!');
}
```

A sample die message would be:

> root could not append 'New Common Quiz Review about to be created with userQuizId of 7316553\n\n' to log file /var/logs/private/do_not_backup/lms2.0_test_errors.log!

Here is the ls -l from the log file location:

```
[userid]@ip-[ip address]:/var/logs/private/do_not_backup$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     www-data          0 Nov 22 20:43 lms2.0_test_errors.log
```

The file is empty as I just created it and am yet to get a successful write to it. Following a `die` output, I changed the owner from `www-data` to `root`, but I left the group as-is.

The PHP page that is quoted-in-part above resides in `/var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/lms/assessment_review.php` on the same server as the target log file. The server itself is running nginx 1.18.0 with PHP 7.4.3 on Ubuntu Linux 20.04.3.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php), that function returns the owner of the file itself, not the process that is executing PHP, check the first two comments

Comment: Nice Q&A! See also: [How to check what user php is running as?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771586/1729441)

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Haas pointed out, get_current_user does not return what I thought it was going to return. As [the first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php#57624) he pointed towards notes, code akin to the following is necessary to get the appropriate userid:

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
```

That showed me that `www-data` is running the process, and once I made them owner of the log file I got the logging I expected.